# \makeatletter without \makeatother

Tags: macros

I'm aware that one can use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to modify LaTeX package internals. I always thought that you have to the first to open a modifier block and the latter to close it, but found this

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\bbibitem#1{\item[]\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string \bibcite {#1} {\the\value{\@listctr }}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatletter  % !
```

to be working.

Shouldn't this fail? Why does it work?

Comment: You simply had the `@` as a letter in the rest of your code/document. Maybe something after it will issue a `\makeatother`, maybe no. Something can fail in strange ways, or not. (Notice that `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do not nest --- they are switches, so `\makeatletter (whatever) \makeatletter (other things) \makeatother` is perfectly legal (although not very useful).

Comment: well the main question is if some code follows that expects @ to be not a letter. I often forget the \makeatother when I test something. Or mistype it as \makeatletter as you did in your snippet and in most cases it is not a problem, but you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: You are a lot less likely to not notice if you forget `\ExplSyntaxOff` ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make `@` a "letter" and don't restore it to "other" then two or three things happen.

- You can access internal commands with `@` in their name within the document.
- `\@` becomes a control word not a control symbol so in `foo\@ .` the space is dropped whereas normally `foo\@ .` would show a space (just as spaces are not dropped after `\$`)
- delimited argments delimited by a non-letter `@` or explicit `\ifcat` tests testing the catcode of `@` will fail (but these probably only occur in artificial test documents)

Comment: @UlrichDiez you know the answer to your question:-)

Comment: On the one hand, I had the feeling that I knew the answer to my question. On the other hand, over the years you and others drew my attention to so many subtleties of TeX/LaTeX that I myself was not aware of, so I always feel a latent uncertainty whether I might have overlooked something again. ;-)